# Coloumb's Law question in relation to a particle put in a dielectric substance

Tags: coulombs-law, dielectric

So, as we know, Coloumb's Law states this equality: $F=\frac{k|q1q2|}{r^2}$

But if we were to put, for example, two particles with the same charge $q$ and a distance $r$ between them in a dielectric substance, the $F$ value would alter. My question is, what makes that $F$ value alter, whether it is the change in charge, change in distance between the particles, or maybe both?

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that the medium you put in between has charges of its own. They will feel the force produced by the charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ and move on the material, the result is that there appears another electric field as a consequence of these charges, which results in a change on the effective force $F$.

Answer (score 0):

The charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ will induce a polarization of the dielectric substance in between them, resulting in a decrease in the force.  The atoms in the dielectric material will reorganize their electronic cloud so it is not longer centered on the nucleus.
[image]

The bulk effect is an induced electric field that is opposite the external field: notice how the polarized atoms act as dipoles 
producing a field opposite the external field:

[image]

and thus a smaller net force on the external charges.

Image credit: F.T. Ulaby, *Applied Electromagnetics*, and Young and Freedman's *University Physics*.

Answer (score 0):

The constant $k$ will change.

Generally, we have $k = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}$. Now, this $\epsilon_0$ is valid only if there is vacuum between the charges.

You need to replace it for $\epsilon$, the permittivity of the given dielectric.